# Where can I find an AVX exponential double-precision function?

Tags: vectorization, simd, avx, exponential, avx2

I was recently researching implementations of vectorized exponential functions. It's actually very simple to find code for single-precision, but very hard to find code for double-precision. I haven't been able to find any implementation of double-precision AVX exponentiation. The code from SSE can almost be adapted but the trick that is generally used to multiply by 2^n does not seem to be adaptable to AVX.

Does anyone know of such an implementation ?

Comment: There's always `_mm256_exp_pd` in Intel's SVML library. Also I believe Agner Fog's vector class library supports `exp` for double precision vectors: http://www.agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.pdf

Comment: Another math library with AVX2 and double precision support is [Yeppp!](https://www.yeppp.info/index.html) .

Comment: The Agner Fog's vector library did the trick pretty well! If you post it as answer, I'll accept it @PaulR

Comment: @BaptisteWicht: thanks for the feedback - glad it worked out for you - I've converted my comment to an answer as you suggest.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using Intel's ICC compiler then there is `_mm256_exp_pd` in the SVML library.

Alternatively Agner Fog's [vector class library](http://agner.org/optimize/vectorclass.pdf) supports `exp` for double precision vectors.

Comment: Agner Fog's vector library is exactly what I was looking for and the code is comprehensive enough.